# NoClassDefFoundError while running java class in eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java class in eclipse using `junit`, i am getting the following error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function

please let me know to solve this issue

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You must add that class (which is probably in a jar-file) and all related, in your classpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you did not add the required jar file in your classpath. The exception is thrown because JRE can't find the class. Please make sure you add all the required jar files in your classpath.